# Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined after migrate angular to v 11

Tags: angular

After I migrate my angular project from 9 to 11 when I serve my project in browser loading this error occurs

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
    at NbViewportRulerAdapter._getWindow (scrolling.js:665)
    at scrolling.js:580
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:368)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:130)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:28209)
    at new ViewportRuler (scrolling.js:578)
    at new NbViewportRulerAdapter (index.js:2405)
    at Object.NbViewportRulerAdapter_Factory [as factory] (index.js:2432)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11145)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:10966)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1209)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1163)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1275
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:402)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28269)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:401)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:174)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:578)
```

What is the cause?
I use **nebular** ui library in my project.

Answer (score 0):

1- npm i patch-package
2 - Make the following changes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI2RE.png)

3- npx patch-package patch-package
4- npx patch-package @nebular/theme
5- Add patch-package to postinstall in packages.json
6 -npm i